# Android 7 localization issue

Tags: android, localization

i have android project with support a few language.String files located in the suitable folders. For example: file string with french, located in folder 'values-fr'. In a run time i want to change language. I have class LocaleHelper

```
public class LocaleHelper {

private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, final String language) {
    String tmpLang = language;
    if (language.length() > 2) {
        tmpLang = language.substring(0, 2);
    }
    persist(context, tmpLang);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, tmpLang);
    }

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, tmpLang);
}

private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
}

private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);

    Resources.getSystem().updateConfiguration(configuration, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    Resources.getSystem().updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
}

public static void clearPersist(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.remove(SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

And in the BaseActivity

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
}
```

When i start my app in the 'french mode'

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, "fr");
```

on Android_Version less then Android7 every things work correct but on Android_Version>=Android7 i have partially localized app. Part of string in the english and part in the french.
P.S
Title in the toolbar has correct locale

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-sidebar-navigation-drawer-with-icons/

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `Locale` class with a country code as a second parameter. E.g. in my code:

```
if (language.equals("ru") {
    locale = new Locale(language, "RU");
} else if (language.equals("en")) {
    locale = new Locale(language, "US");
}
```